# Visual Studio Xamarin project not recognizing OnePlus 5T

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have been working on a mobile application using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2017. I have previously been deploying and debugging my app onto my old Samsung S6 and I had no problems with that. However I recently upgraded my phone to a OnePlus 5T and I am trying to build and deploy the app to this phone. However I cannot find the device on VS when I connect it.

I have allowed for USB Debugging and also I installed ADB drivers from Clockwork Mod (https://adb.clockworkmod.com/) but not really sure how to set it up so I can build to my phone.

Any ideas why this wouldn't be appearing for me?

Comment: Put VS aside for a second and start with ensuring that this device makes the `adb devices` list. If it's not making this list, then you will have to look into ensuring the correct drivers are installed and that USB debugging is enabled.

Comment: @JonDouglas how do i check that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> About Phone -> tap the "Build Number" 7 times to enable developer mode.

Then go to Settings again, search "USB", find USB Debugging -> hit the switch to enable it.

Then VS should recognize the device when plugged in and target is Android.

Comment: This definitely worked. Not sure why it's not selected as the answer.